# If ("condición" is null) no me funciona C#

Tags: c#, android, condiciones, xamarin

Tengo un `if` donde necesito revisar si el string devuelto viene null o viene con un link. He intentado varias formas pero se me sigue yendo al `Try-Catch` porque me viene con un `null` y no lo captura el if.

He intentado con estas variaciones pero nada funciona.
El error es el siguiente:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (datos.Results[n].PosterPath.ToString() is null)

if (datos?.Results[n]?.PosterPath.ToString() is null)
```

El resto del código no es relevante pero últimamente todo mundo lo pide mucho así que acá lo dejo de una vez:

```
HttpClient clienti = new HttpClient();

                var responsei = await clienti.GetStringAsync(URL).ConfigureAwait(true);

                var datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(responsei);

if (datos?.Results[n]?.PosterPath.ToString() is null)
                            {
                                Photo.Globales.ImagenesList.Add("https://cdn.thinglink.me/gfx/icons/missing-thumbnail.png");
                            }
                            else
                            Photo.Globales.ImagenesList.Add("https://" + datos.Results[n].PosterPath.ToString());
```

Ideas?

[image: NULL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El único problema que se ve es que `Results` sea `Null`, por lo que tienes que revisar que no lo sea utilizando otro operador `?`:

```
if (datos?.Results?[n]?.PosterPath is null)
```

Comment: Hey, gracias @Carlos. Tu respuesta me dio la idea de remover el ".ToString()" aparentemente era esa parte (el hacer una conversion con null) lo que estaba dando el error. Al remover eso de los IF funciona perfecto. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
if(datos!=null && datos.Results != null && datos.Results[n] != null)  
{
   if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(datos.Results[n].PosterPath)
   {
      //Mi código 
   }
}
```

Primero se pregunta si datos no es nulo y si datos.Results tampoco es null, si se cumple esta condición entonces se pregunta si PosterPath no está nulo, vacio o solo tiene espacios, espero te sirva

Comment: Ya lo intente y nada, no funciona. Actualice con imagen de lo que devuelve el "PosterPath" y el error que me da.

Comment: Mira ver ahora esto nuevo